# Attribute not showing in Layered Navigation ( drop down is disabled )

Tags: magento, navigation, layered

Attribute not showing in Layered Navigation ( drop down is disabled )

I want certain attributes to apply to a certain category .. but the drop down is disabled ...
Please help!

Use In Layered Navigation Select Box Is not clickable

Can be used only with catalog input type Dropdown, Multiple Select and Price

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set an attribute that has a different type than Dropdown, Multiple Select and Price as Filterable (Use In Layered Navigation).

You can only use those attribute types in layered navigation.